# Create an array of the last 24 hours using moment.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to create an array of the last 24 hours, with values being simply the hours followed by an AM/PM (not minutes, seconds, or even the calendar date), in Moment.js.

It kind of works right now, but is giving the entire date data (Sun May 06 2018 22:24:29 GMT-0700) in each element when I only need the time in hours:

JS Code:

```js
var hoursPerDay = 24;
var time = [];

function timeOneDay() {
  var formattedTime;
  for (i = 0; i < hoursPerDay + 1; i++) { //fill in all of the hours
    formattedTime = (moment().subtract(i, "hours"));
    formattedTime.format("hA"); //give the time in format X AM/PM
    time.unshift(formattedTime); //add to beginning of array
  } //do this for all 24 hours
}
timeOneDay();
console.log(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moment.format()` is returning the formatted value. You were not storing it inside a variable

```js
var hoursPerDay = 24;
var time = [];

function timeOneDay(){
    var formattedTime;
    for(i =0; i < hoursPerDay+1 ; i++){ //fill in all of the hours
        formattedTime = (moment().subtract(i, "hours")).format("hA");  //give the time in format X AM/PM
        time.unshift(formattedTime);  //add to beginning of array
    }                                //do this for all 24 hours
}
timeOneDay();
console.log(time);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```